# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method pretaxamount(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-edittext

I have designed a form in which I have an EditText whose id is "Pre_tax_amount_ET"

and m getiing this error in Log

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method pretaxamount(View) in a parent 
or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText with id 'Pre_tax_amount_ET'
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:307)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:266)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have now Idea what its all about Could someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

Your view(Edittext) do not exists on the your parent or inflated xml file. check if your xml file contains that view. and if possible post your xml code as well

Comment: Hi thankzs 
I just removed this from EditText <requestFocus />. and it is working fine now

Comment: your welcome ! if you found it help full dont forget to accept the answer :)